# OpenShift 3 - FileSystem Choices Pros and Cons

Tags: filesystems, openshift

I am about to upgrade to the OpenShift Pro package. This will give me several choices for the file system. I have used EBS on the starter package as it is the only choice.

My question is:

**What are the pros and cons of the different file systems available?**

I will initially be setting up two regular web sites with low-volume traffic...

Comment: I now know that there is ONLY one file system currently available as Will Gordon correctly states. Therefore this question is (currently) irrelevant and should possibly be deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time, OpenShift Online, both Starter and Pro, only offer persistent volumes backed by AWS EBS volumes. You see the various Access Modes available for the different volume plug-ins in the [OpenShift Documentation](https://docs.openshift.com/online/architecture/additional_concepts/storage.html#pv-access-modes).

EBS backed persistent volumes(PVs) can only be mounted by a single pod. So, for example, if you had a web pod and a database pod, you would need 2 separate PVs. This reduces complexity and prevents any race conditions of multiple applications accessing the same PV at the same time.